# Values ​are not going to the database with signals

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, signals

I'm using a signal to register a user in the Profile table, every time a User is registered in the Django User. I'm able to get the results of username and email, however, the first and last name are not being assigned.

Model Perfil

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="first name", blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="last name", blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, verbose_name="email address", blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username.username
```

Signal new_profile

```
def new_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
user_db = User.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).values().first()
if created:
    Perfil.objects.create(
        username = instance
    )
    Perfil.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).update(
        first_name = user_db['first_name'],
        last_name = user_db['last_name'],
        email = user_db['email']
    )
post_save.connect(new_profile, sender=User)
```

Note: I already tried to create with everything together and my measure of desperation was to try to update after having created.

Print of the table without the last_name and the first_name but with the email.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the situation. The problem was in the way django injects data into the database, apparently, it creates and after the update. Here's the solution:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def new_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Perfil.objects.create(
        username = instance,
        email = instance.email,
    )
else:
    if not hasattr(instance, "Perfil"):
        Perfil.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).update(
        ultimo_nome = instance.last_name,
        primeiro_nome = instance.first_name,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you used a dot instead of parenthesis because your `user_db` is an object, not a dictionary. (after removed `.values()`)

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings 

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def new_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user_db = User.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).first()
    if created:
        Perfil.objects.create(
            username = instance
        )
        Perfil.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).update(
            first_name = user_db.first_name,
            last_name = user_db.last_name,
            email = user_db.email
        )
    post_save.connect(new_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: I did what you told me and even then it doesn't insert the data in the first_name and last_name, both directly in create and update.

Comment: do you have a receiver tag on top of the signal? I update the answer please check if you don't have it

Comment: I'm starting to get this error now.

user_db = User.objects.filter(username__exact=instance).first()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: I solved this error from string to object, but I still don't get the first_name and last_name information.